# How i show geojson FeatureCollection in a leaflet Map?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I've exported shapefile data to geoJson with Qgis, before i try published in leaflet map, but it's not working.

The code i've used is below, where geojson file is "gj2.geojson".

Where is wrong?

GEOJSON is like:

```html
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "gj2",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "DN": 976 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -36.647916182333311, -8.742916206999967 ], [ -36.647082848999979, -8.742916206999967 ], [ -36.647082848999979, -8.743749540333299 ], [ -36.647916182333311, -8.743749540333299 ], [ -36.647916182333311, -8.742916206999967 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "DN": 971 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -36.647082848999979, -8.742916206999967 ], [ -36.646249515666646, -8.742916206999967 ], [ -36.646249515666646, -8.745416206999966 ], [ -36.647082848999979, -8.745416206999966 ], [ -36.647082848999979, -8.742916206999967 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "DN": 966 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -36.646249515666646, -8.742916206999967 ], [ -36.645416182333307, -8.742916206999967 ], [ -36.645416182333307, -8.743749540333299 ], [ -36.646249515666646, -8.743749540333299 ], [ -36.646249515666646, -8.742916206999967 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "DN": 975 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -36.647916182333311, -8.743749540333299 ], [ -36.647082848999979, -8.743749540333299 ], [ -36.647082848999979, -8.744582873666634 ], [ -36.647916182333311, -8.744582873666634 ], [ -36.647916182333311, -8.743749540333299 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "DN": 965 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -36.646249515666646, -8.743749540333299 ], [ -36.645416182333307, -8.743749540333299 ], [ -36.645416182333307, -8.744582873666634 ], [ -36.646249515666646, -8.744582873666634 ], [ -36.646249515666646, -8.743749540333299 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature"....
```

THE CODE i've try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <title>GeoJSON tutorial - Leaflet</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.4.4/proj4.js"></script>

 <style>
  html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
  }
  #map {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }
 </style>

 
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script src="geojson.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
 var map = L.map('map').setView([-9,-36], 13);

 L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
   '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
   'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox.light'
 }).addTo(map);


var geojson = L.geoJSON('gj2.geojson').addTo(map);
 

 
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are trying to specify a filename as a parameter to L.geoJSON(..) but it needs a Javascript object containing the geoJson definition.  Add the following to the beginning of your geoJson file (geojson.js):

```
var myGeoJson =
```

So that the file starts like this:

```
var myGeoJson = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "gj2",
...
...
```

And then add a semicolon at the end of the file.  This way you have a variable 'myGeoJson' representing the geoJson definition.

Then change this line:

```
var geojson = L.geoJSON('gj2.geojson').addTo(map);
```

to this:

```
var geojson = L.geoJSON(myGeoJson).addTo(map);
```

The Leaflet GeoJSON example page has a similar example towards the top of the page here: [Using GeoJSON with Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/)